# setMultiChoiceItems Displaying CheckBoxs on the Left of Lable?

Tags: android, checkbox

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html), the `setMultiChoiceItems(...)` method "... will have a check mark displayed to the right of the text for each checked item."  However, for some reason my checkboxes are appearing on the left hand side of the text rather than on the right, and it looks most odd.

At one stage my manifest file contained the line: `android:supportsRtl="true"`.  I have since changed this to false but the checkboxes still appear to the left of the text.  Any ideas what I have done?

This is the tutorial I've been using to create the dialogue:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#DialogFragment

Answer (score 0):

[image]Please use below code

```
     <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="Check box One"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAlignment="textStart"
            tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

Comment: Thanks jaffar, but I'm afraid I don't quite follow what you're saying there.
I'm creating the object using a builder in java code with the line:
`builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, mSelectedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {...});`

Then calling: `builder.create();`
as per the tutorial.  Are you suggesting I should create an additional Layout file?